# How do I use std::constructible_from

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am starting on C++ concepts and have trouble using them.

E.g. Here I want to make an optimistic create_unique function.

```
template<typename Arg, constructible_from<Arg> CreatedClass >       *1
unique_ptr<CreatedClass>
create_unique( Arg && arg ) {
    return make_unique<CreatedClass>( forward<Arg>( arg ) );
}
template<typename CreatedClass, typename Arg, 
         enable_if_t< !is_constructible<CreatedClass, Arg>::value, int > = 0>   *2
unique_ptr<CreatedClass>
create_unique( Arg && arg ) {
    throw runtime_error( "CreatedClass is not constructible from arg." );
}

int main() {
    auto x = create_unique2<string>("Hello"s);    *3
    // auto x = create_unique2<string>(42);
}
```

This does not compile because in *1 CreatedClass is placed after Arg. So in order for that to compile I have to explicitly specify both template arguments.

```
    auto x = create_unique2<string, string>("Hello"s);
```

If I write

```
template<constructible_from<string> CreatedClass, typename Arg >       *1
unique_ptr<CreatedClass>
create_unique( Arg && arg ) {
    return make_unique<CreatedClass>( forward<Arg>( arg ) );
}
```

then *3 compiles, but now CreatedClass is no longer dependent on Arg.

After this, how do I specify the *negative* case *2? It seems a bit *un-clean* to use the old-school enable_if.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use a `requires` clause on the template header?

Comment: No. I am just trying to understand how to use concepts. So `requires` is the way to do this, like shown in the answer by Barry below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
template <typename CreatedClass, typename Arg>
    requires std::constructible_from<CreatedClass, Arg>
auto create_unique(Arg&&) -> std::unique_ptr<CreatedClass>
```

You don't *have* to use the terser constraint syntax - `requires` is always available.

The negative case would then be an overload with no constraint:

```
template <typename CreatedClass, typename Arg>
auto create_unique(Arg&&) -> std::unique_ptr<CreatedClass>
```

The more constrained case would be preferred. But this is highly questionable, why would you want to defer this error to runtime? Seems way better to diagnose at compile type by just not having a viable overload of `create_unique`...

Comment: I too prefer compile-time diagnosis, but sometimes you have to do things differently. Especially when working on big shared code-bases.